# Estimating number of conditional operators in C

Tags: c

I need to find the exact number of conditional operators **if** and **if/else** though **C**.

Is there some particular function I could use to search for a pattern and output results? Basically, it's just an uncompiled C program that I need to analyze by estimating the amount of usage of conditional statements.

Comment: Yeah, parse the source code. There are a few libraries for that.

Comment: Don't forget that ?: is a conditional operator. And that && and || function as if they were conditionals. And that macros may contain these.

Comment: What happens if some of the conditionals are `#ifdef`'ed out. Do they still count toward your total? Parsing of course is the way, but if your "exact number" requirement is not actually a requirement, then you can come up with a simple commandline using grep to find out a reasonable estimate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into Clang. It has has an excellent C parser, and a library, cindex, for traversing though the AST. See http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html for getting started and CINDEX.html">http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group_CINDEX.html for the API documentation.

Comment: I'm afraid my question is quite basic and though I'm not looking for any advanced solutions using libraries and such. I just need to find a string and count its number of appearance.

Comment: You might want to edit the question, then. String-search is a different issue from semantic search.

Comment: Ok, so then how do I search for a string in C?

Comment: The strstr function (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strstr.html ) could be of help then.